# Finding the radius of convergence for $\frac{1}{(3 - x)(1 + x)^{2}}$ at $x_{0} = 0$ and $x_{0} = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am having trouble with the problem

> Find the radius of convergence for $f(x) = \frac{1}{(3 - x)(1 +
>  x)^{2}}$ at $x_{0} = 0$ and $x_{1} = 1$.

Usually, when I'm trying to find radius of convergence, I'm given some sort of series (like, a summation). This isn't the case here, and I'm confused as to what I'm supposed to do. This is a problem in the exercise. It is in the section for power series. Also, I have this formula for the radius of convergence $R$:

$$R = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_{n}|^{1/n}},$$

but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use that here either.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Maybe it has something to do with the standard Taylor series form? Like,

$$f(x) = f(x_{0}) + f'(x_{0})(x - x_{0}) + f''(x_{0})(x - x_{0})^{2}/2! \ldots $$

Also, in case it matters, by Partial Fractions, you can write

$$\frac{1}{(3-x)(1 + x)^{2}} = \frac{1}{16(x + 1)} + \frac{1}{4(x+1)^{2}} - \frac{1}{16(x - 3)}. $$

The first few terms of the Taylor series expansion about $x_{0} = 0$ is given by

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{5}{9}x + \frac{22}{27}x^{2} - \frac{86}{81}x^{3} + \frac{319}{243}x^{4} + \cdots $$

(I don't have a closed term for the sum, but these are the first terms explicitly computed. Looks like the denominator is just powers of $3$. Not sure about the numerator though...)

Comment: The radius of convergence is the distance to the nearest pole (place where the denominator vanishes, when considered as a function of a complex variable).

Comment: hi @Ethan Bolker, I don't know what a pole is. this is in a real analysis book. i think poles are from complex analysis

Comment: Poles are from complex analysis but they influence real power series. The series for $1/(1+x^2)$ converges on $(-1, 1)$ because the denominator vanishes at $x=i$. Perhaps you're not allowed to know this yet.

Comment: I guess not, but it kind of makes sense. A pole is like an asymptote, I think? Do you know about any other ways that this problem can be solved?

Comment: Well in your examples the poles are real. The power series surely couldn't converge to the function there, so the distance to the pole is an upper bound on the radius of convergence. I think you will have to wait now for someone to provide a complete answer.

Comment: Maybe you could first find a series expansion for $f$ at $0, 1$ respectively, then determine the radius?

Comment: i did that on paper but didn't get anywhere. let me add it to my original post @xbh

Comment: I Updated it @xbh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, write the given series as a power one around some given point, then evaluate the radius of convergence.

For example, about $\;x=1\;$ :

$$\frac1{(3-x)(x+1)^2}=-\frac1{16}\frac1{x-3}+\frac1{16}\frac1{x+1}+\frac14\frac1{(x+1)^2}=$$

$$=\frac1{32}\frac1{1-\frac{x-1}2}+\frac1{32}\frac1{1+\frac{x-1}2}+\frac1{16}\frac1{\left(1+\frac{x-1}2\right)^2}=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac1{32}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(x-1)^n}{2^n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x-1)^n}{2^n}+2\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(x-1)^n}{2^n}\right)^2\right]$$

Now, if you had to write down a power series then that'd be really tedious, though not quite difficult, but you're only required to calculate the convergence radius, and that seems pretty easy as all the three series' convergence radius above is $\;1\;$ around the point we want, so it must be

$$\left|\frac{x-1}2\right|<1\iff |x-1|<2$$

Note that in fact all we needed above is what follows after the simple fractions decomposition, as we already there have the basic $\;\frac{x-1}2\;$ thing we shall need. To write down the infinite series is just for fun...

Comment: Check carefully, in case you want/need to do it, the signs of the simple fractions as I have some minor doubts about that...but that *really* is irrelevant for the direct question you've asked.

Comment: In the first summation term, why is it $(x - 1)^{2}$ rather than $(x - 1)^{n}$?

Comment: @joseph Simple typo. Corrected.

Comment: I think your partial fraction decomposition in the first equation is incorrect. The coefficient of $\frac{1}{4}$ should be $+$ not $-$.

Comment: @joseph It really doesn't matter, as already written there. You can do it correctly. The important point is already there...

Answer (score 0):

If you represent $\frac {1}{(3-x)(1+x)^2}$ as a Taylor series, centered at the points identified above that Taylor series will have a finite radius.  There is enough information presented in the question to find these radii without deriving the entire series.

However, if you represent the function as a Laurent series, you have more choices in how you represent the series and depending on those choices the series will converge in different annuli.

The trick comes down to finding the discontinuities of the function.  Since the Taylor series is continuous, it is going to diverge as these discontinuities approach.

Comment: is this a good way to do it? the taylor series representation of the function looks very ugly http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power+series+of+1%2F((3+-+x)(1+%2B+x)%5E(2))

Comment: If you work out the Taylor series centered at $0,$ you are going to get something of the form $\sum A (\frac {x}{3})^n + B (-1)^nx^n + Cn(-1)^n x^n$

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts. This might not be the original purpose of the exercise, but this is my guess.

According to your partial fraction decomposition, and using the well-know power series $(1-x)^{-1} = \sum_0^\infty x^n$ for $x \in (-1,1)$, at $x=0$, we have
\begin{align*}
f(x)&= \frac 1{16}\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n x^n - \frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left( \frac 1{4(x+1)} \right) + \frac 1{48} \cdot \frac 1{1 - x/3} \\
&= \frac 1{16}\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n x^n - \frac 14 \cdot\frac {\mathrm d }{\mathrm dx}\left( \sum_0^\infty (-1)^n x^n \right) + \frac 1{48} \cdot \sum_0^\infty \frac {x^n}{3^n}\\
&= \frac 1{16}\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n x^n - \frac 14  \sum_0^\infty (n+1)(-1)^{n+1} x^{n}  + \frac 1{48} \cdot \sum_0^\infty \frac {x^n}{3^n}\\
&= \sum_0^\infty \left(\frac {(-1)^n}{16} + \frac 14 (n+1)(-1)^{n+1} +\frac 1{16 \cdot 3^{n+1}} \right) x^n,
\end{align*}
and all of these computations are valid iff $|x|<1$ and $|x/3|<1$. Conclusively the radius  is $1$. You might try to compute again by the formula.

At $x=1$, just let $y = x-1$, then $x = y+1$ and 
$$
f(x) =g(y) = \frac 1{(2-y)(2+y)^2},
$$ 
you could do the similar thing like above to give the power series at $y=0$. You could see that the operations are valid iff $|y/2|<1$, hence $|y|<2$ and the radius is $2$.